# How to check divisibility by 97

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for rule to check divisibility by **97** for big numbers. For example, for numbers with 26 digits. Thanks.

Comment: A digit-based rule can be made by looking at 10^n mod the number in question, so you want to check for divisibility by 97 of the ones place plus 10 times the ten place plus 3 times the hundreds place plus 30 times the thousands place etc. Eventually this will loop...

Comment: @Ian  "Eventually."  10 is a primitive root of 97, so that's going to be a big loop.

Comment: Can we assume the number is written in base $98$? or better yet, base $97$?

Comment: @Ian would you please give more details? I guess what you suggest, leads me to what I'm looking after.

Comment: @Mazdak The point is that if you write a number $n$ as $\sum_i a_i 10^i$ then you can sum up the remainders of $a_i 10^i$ in division by $97$ to get the remainder of $n$ in division by $97$. Each summand will be $a_i$ times the remainder of $10^i$ in division by $97$. You can tabulate the remainders of $10^i$ in division by $97$ and then do the summation by reading off digits. The result will be another number with the same remainder when divided by $97$ (in particular it will be divisible by $97$ if and only if the original number was).

Comment: (Cont.)  The problem here is that the list of precomputed remainders you get is rather long: if I recall correctly, since 10 and 97 are coprime, you will need to store all 97 numbers $\{ 10^i \% 97 : i=0,1,\dots,96 \}$.

Comment: @Ian You're totally right. You should post your comment as true answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ian, yes, this is another problem. but, thanks to your comments, I could write another computer algorithm except that `n % 97` . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to compute $n\%m$ starts by writing $n$ in some base. Say you pick base $10$, so you write $n=\sum_i a_i 10^i$ where $a_i \in \{ 0,1,\dots,9 \}$. Now compute $10^i \% m$ for a sufficiently large segment of $i$'s that you find the cycle. When $m$ and the base are coprime (as here), Euler's theorem tells you that the cycle will have at most $\varphi(m)$ elements (not counting the duplicate at the end), where $\varphi$ is the totient function. In particular $\varphi(p)=p-1$ for a prime $p$.

So here you can precompute $\{ 10^i \% 97 : i=1,\dots,95 \}$. Say these numbers are $r_1,\dots,r_{95}$ and also introduce $r_0=1$. Then $n\%97=\left ( \sum_i a_i r_{i\%96} \right )\%97$. You can then do this computation by using this algorithm recursively (stopping when you get a sum that is less than 97), or you could take moduli as you carry out the summation, or you could follow various similar options.

Comment: I'm curious why I am being downvoted. I actually only posted this upon the OP confirming that they like this approach in the comments. I actually don't think this approach is really significantly better than long division. Is the problem with the use of % notation rather than conventional math notation for modular arithmetic? Or is it an objection to the content?

Answer (score 3):

I just looked into this and I formed my own way of doing this. For example, let's take a number that we know is a multiple of 97, like $547627565$, i.e $97*5645645$.

This number contains 9 digits. Let the no. of digits of the given number be $n$. Take the first (n-2) digits. So here in this case it would be 5476275. Now do the following;

$$547627565-5476275(97)=16428890\tag{Step 1.}\label{1}$$

So i.e; $(the\; number) - 97(the\; number\; with\; the\; first \;(n-2)\; digits)$

Now do the same step and take the first $(n-2)$ digits of this. And repeat the process

$$16428890-164288\left(97\right)=1202509\tag{Step 2.}\label{2}$$
$$1202509-12025\left(97\right)=36084\tag{Step 3.}\label{3}$$
$$36084-360\left(97\right)=1164\tag{Step 4.}\label{4}$$
$$1164-11\left(97\right)=97\tag{Step 5.}\label{5}$$

So if any number after this transformation/process ends up at $97$, Then it is a multiple of $97$. Also note that even for a 9-digit number, this takes only 5-steps.

Comment: What you're doing here is really not that different from long division, you just subtract off a number that you know is a multiple of 97 from the current number. It does work, though.

Comment: @Ian, yes but instead or just randomly subtracting $97$ off a number, I did like a way to do so which I think works efficiently with the case of $97$. And also maybe for 97, it is better to divide and check instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$ denote a $n$ digit number equal to $a_n+10a_{n-1}+100a_{n-2}\cdots$. Then, we can write the following: $\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}a_n}=10\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}}+a_n=10(\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_n-1}-29a_n)+291a_n$. And since $97|291$, then $97|291a_n$ and $97|10(\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}}-29a_n)$ implies $97|\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}$. We can also ignore the $10$ factor. We can keep doing this recursively.

So our algorithm is:

1. Take the last digit of a number. Let’s call it $e$.
2. Subtract $e$ from the number and divide by $10$.
3. Subtract $29\cdot e$ from the number.
4. Repeat Steps 1-3 as many times as you want.

Comment: This is about as complicated as simply doing the division!

Comment: take the number over 100, times by 3 and add to the last 2 digits as a number.

Comment: $\large \begin{align}{\rm i.e.}\,\ \bmod 97\!:\ &0 \equiv a\!+\!10b  \iff 0 \equiv -29(a\!+\!10b) \equiv -29a\! +\! b\\[.5em]
{\rm since}\ \ \ \ &\!\!\dfrac{1}{10} \equiv \dfrac{10}{100} \equiv  \dfrac{10\!-\!97}3 \equiv -29\end{align}$